# Mylyn BugZilla connector throws Http error: Moved Temporarily

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla, mylyn

Trying to configure Mylyn to work with BugZilla. I get error

> Http error: Moved Temporarily

I tried setting proxy (socks), http authentication but the same problem. Nothing works

Any one facing this problem. Please help...

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug for that in eclipse.org bugzilla [#221162](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=221162)

Anyway I changed my repository URL from http to https and it works fine then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried https also but fails with the following error

I/O Error occurred while communicating with https://bug.xxxxxxxxxx.com